# Usage of may and might

Tags: grammar, usage

Andy murray "may "miss ATP Finals or Andy murray "might" miss ATP finals.which one is correct? And please explain when to use 'may' and 'might'.

Answer (score 3):

Either "may" or "might" is valid here and they mean the same thing.

If you say "this might happen", you are saying that it is possible, but not certain.

"May" can also mean a possibility in this sense. But it can also mean that someone has permission. If your boss says, "You may go home once you have finished this task", he means that he is giving you permission to go home.

"May" can be ambiguous. "Bob may go home once he finishes this task" could mean that someone has given Bob permission to go home, or it could mean that you are not sure if Bob will go home or not.

"May" is also used as a very mild form of command. Like, "You may leave your application form in the box over there." Usually this means that you MUST leave the form in the box, but it is expressed as permission rather than a command to be polite.